# How can I find the temporal complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

```
fun xpto(n: Int, m: Int): Int {
    return if (n / m == 0) 0 else 1 + xpto(n / m, m)
}
```

How does m influence the temporal complexity? My first thought was O(n), but I wasn't sure.

Comment: What is the second function `xpto` about? Please ask only one question. Secondly, what is the role of `var n = n`? Looks like a no-operation... Thirdly, does `BinarySearch` know what the size of the array is (as it does not get a size parameter)?

Comment: The 2nd xpto basically returns 0 when n<m. When n becomes a "0.xx" because it's an Integer when divided by m it equals 0. And xpto returns 0.
var n = n, is made in order to make n mutable, so you can do "--n". You wouldn't be able to decrement a parameter otherwise. Binary search returns -1 if the b[--n] element is not present in the "a" array.

Comment: Can you limit your question to one question?

Comment: How can I find the temporal complexity of the 2nd algorithm?

Comment: Please update your question (use edit link below it), so to make this about *one* question. You risk that it will be closed otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function divides the first argument by the second, and uses that quotient again as the first argument for a next call, for as long as this quotient is non-zero. For positive integers, the number of times a recursive call is made is thus equal to the greatest power  such that

/  >= 1, or

>=

Hence the number of recursive calls  is

= <sub>⌊</sub>log<sub>⌋</sub>

This is also the value that the function will return, as with each recursive call 1 is added to the result coming back from recursion.

### Time Complexity

Assuming that we can consider division as a constant-time operation, we thus have a time complexity of O(log). The value of  (i.e. the base of the logarithm) is not relevant in big O notation, as it provides an [upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Note how for a given value of , an increasing (absolute) value of  will *not inccrease* the time spent on the algorithm.

However, there are categories of large  and  where where we can lower the asymptotic upper bound. For instance, in the category where  < , the complexity is O(1). For other categories it could be anything else between O(1) and O(log). So for all categories together, we have O(log) as upper bound.

All of the following time complexity expressions are true for the algorithm:

- Asymptotic upper bound: O(log)
- Asymptotic lower bound: Ω(1)
- Asymptotic tight bound: ϴ(log)

### Negative input

The sign of the arguments is not of influence as the number of recursive calls only depends on the absolute value of both arguments.

If at least one of the arguments is negative we must also assume that integer division (in the actual programming language) will round ***towards zero***, as otherwise the algorithm may get into infinite recursion, always producing a quotient of -1.

### Restrictions

- should be non-zero, as otherwise there will be a division by zero exception.
- abs() should not be 1, as this will lead to infinite recursion when  is non-zero. See [log base 1 of 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413713/log-base-1-of-1) for a related discussion.

Comment: What if the arguments are negative integers?

Comment: Have thought about it? You'll find out that if  is negative, the sign of the first argument () will toggle at each next recursive call. And if  is positive, then  will retain its original sign in each recursive call. But what really matters, is that the absolute value of  will evolve in just the same way, until the quotient is zero, and so the number of recursive calls is the same for `xpto(n, m)`, `xpto(-n, m)`, `xpto(n, -m)`, or `xpto(-n, -m)`.

Comment: O(log n) and O(log_m(n)) aren't the same complexity classes when m is an input, although it's correct to say the algorithm is O(log n) because that's a larger class (when m is an integer). That is, the algorithm is O(log n) and Theta(log_m(n)) but not Theta(log n).

Comment: Yes, this is an important remark. Big-O gives an upper bound. For a tight bound  must be kept in the expression: ϴ(logₘ). Extended my answer to cover this. Thanks, @Paul.